# Does the phrasal verb "I need off this place" mean the same as "I want out of this place"?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

In informal US English, "I want out of this room" means the desire to get out of that room.

But I've also heard this being said: I need off this room.

Does it mean the same?

Comment: 'I need off this place' would (I suppose) involve levitation, perhaps. Or a payment to NASA or Elon Musk.

Comment: It might be appropriate if you're working on a ranch.

Comment: Maybe err ... probably not.  Better is 'I need to be outta this room or place'.

Comment: The standard way to express this in English is: I want out of this place; or I need to get out of here. "off this place" sounds like a non-English speaker. As Nigel J says: it would mean you are on top of a building, for example, and would be quite odd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "I need off this place" if the affirmative is normally expressed with the preposition "on," for example, *on the farm, on the ranch*.

But watch out.  If the thing you're on isn't a *place*, but a *thing,* then your phrase won't work.  For example: John is on a train.  He wants off.  In other words, he wants off the train.  (You can't say, "He wants off this place" because the train isn't exactly a place.)

Now let's look more closely at what happens with the *room*.  Since no one would ever say, "I am on the room," you can't say "I need off this place" in that case.

However, you can say

> I need out.

Or

> I need to get out of this place.

Comment: off this place is not at all normal. Off the train or plane, OK. Your first sentence makes no sense to me.

Comment: @Lambie - It works for me for ranch or farm.  See the comment from Hot Licks above.

Comment: @Lambie Attested usage includes *I need off this island*  [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=AQeMAgAAQBAJ&lpg=PA63&dq=%22need%20off%20this%22&pg=PA63#v=onepage&q=%22need%20off%20this%22&f=false). I can imagine someone being on an island and saying *I need off this place*. Having said that, it is certainly a rarely used construction, as it doesn't appear at all in searches of either google books or internet as a whole, save for a comment in one cached reddit page (the last result [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22need+off+this+place%22&num=100&hl=en&gbv=1&prmd=ivns&filter=0)).

Comment: @linguisticturn Yes, that makes sense purely because: one is on an island or off it. But one is not said to be "on or off a place" in the sense of person being somewhere.  You might say: off this farm or ranch, off or on this boat, off or on this wavelength, off or on this bus, train or plane. etc. I still say one does not normally say: off or on a place. And certainly not: I need off this place. But one does say: I need off this boat. I need off this committee. Wherever on/off is actually idiomatically used. Off/on does not really collocate idiomatically with the noun place.